# If Statement with clear cell

Tags: excel, if-statement

How could i rewrite this to include a statement for IF H8 has no data then H12 (cell where formula is) will be 0.

```
=13.2+IF(H8>30,(H8-30)*0.6,0)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the whole formula in another IF():

```
=IF(H8<>"",13.2+IF(H8>30,(H8-30)*0.6,0),0)
```

Comment: @damn you scott I was in the middle of typing my answer!

Comment: @ForwardEd well, all I can say is, "Type faster." :)

Comment: Thanks, it has cleared the cell (H12). I have added £0 into the last set of speech marks which now put £0 into H12 (so it matches the rest of the cells) however it seems to have removed my conditional format.

Comment: I was originally putting it after the 13.2 instead of before.

Comment: sorry just put `0` instead of `""`.  see edit.  The way you have it, it will put a string that will not fire the conditionla formatting.

Comment: @LRogers remember to mark the answers as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  You will need to wait till the question is 15 minutes old.  You probably should go through your history and mark the ones correct also.